Can I apply for a B1/B2 visa after ESTA?
I travelled on an ESTA and stayed in the US for just about 90 days and returned. Can I now apply for a B1/B2 visa from the UK to visit again in a few weeks, as I need to attend a business conference in the US and I am representing my own business.
Any experiences?

How long ago did you travel to the US for the 90 days?  Why can't you travel again under the Visa Waiver Program (ESTA)?

Why can't you continue traveling with ESTA? Has anything changed since your last visit? It is unclear why you'd even ask this question

Pretty sure there’s nothing to prevent you from applying. However if you still have a valid ESTA, why can’t you travel again for business using that? Related question What is the minimum wait before I may re-enter the US after a 90 day visit on the VWP

"in a few weeks" - you may find a few weeks isn't long enough to apply for a B1 visa.  See https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/global-visa-wait-times.html
